# Haskell Lambda help - Splitting up terms from a lambda-term input

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am trying to create a function in which given a **lambda term** will return all separate lambda terms

Here is my **findT** function:

```
findT :: T -> [T]
findT (V x) = []
findT (L x n) = [] ++ findT n
findT (A  n m) = [n] ++ findT m
```

When I run this function on two separate tests, it works with the first but not the second.

Comment: I assume `S` is a `Variable`?

Comment: Yep, it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look if `n` is a `Variable`, and if so, do not include it, for example with:

```
findTerms :: Term -> [Term]
findTerms (Variable x) = []
findTerms (Lambda x n) = findTerms n
findTerms (Apply (Variable _) m) = findTerms m
findTerms (Apply n m) = n : findTerms m
```

Here if the first parameter of `Apply` is a `Variable _`, we will thus not consider it, otherwise we will yield `n` in the list.

You probably should also *recurse* on `n` and `m`, since that can contain terms as well. For a lambda you then can return the lambda itself:

```
findTerms :: Term -> [Term]
findTerms (Variable x) = []
findTerms l@(Lambda _ _) = [l]
findTerms (Apply n m) = findTerms n ++ findTerms m
```

Comment: Yep @WillemVanOnsem, that has done the trick of skipping past the variables! But with example2, it still doesn't split up the terms. For example:                                                                                        
`*Main> example2
S ((\a. \x. (\y. a c) x b) (\f. \x. x) 0)
*Main> findTerms example2
[(\a. \x. (\y. a c) x b) (\f. \x. x)]
*Main>`

Comment: @Jake: and you want to include `\y . a c` as well?

Comment: Yes, so I believe the function should return `[\a. \x. (\y. a c) x b,\f. \x. x] `

Comment: @Jake: so you want to return `Apply` items, given it does not further consists out of `Apply`s? Is it possible to make more specific what you mean with "terms", since a lambda expression term is also a *variable*, *lambda* expression, and an *apply*.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to follow the grammar of N ::= x | A | N N , as a list.

Comment: @Jake: but then variables, lambdas, and applies need to be included in the list? Is it possible to give a more "*crisp*" description of exactly the result you aim for?

Comment: of course, this might help.                
Just before attempting the **findTerms** function, I have a function called **stripTerms** which returns: `a pair (listXi, N) Where listXi = x1,....,Xn and N (NOT an abstraction)` from the lambda-term `lambdax1...lambdaxn.N`. Now I want to complete **findTerms** which gives the abstractions A in a lambda-term, following the grammar N ::= x | A | N N as a list. So for example: inputting `S ((\a. \x. (\y. a c) x b) (\f. \x. x) 0)` into findTerms should return `[\a. \x. (\y. a c) x b,\f. \x. x]` _note the comma!_

Comment: @Jake: and why is `\y . a c` not part of the list as an individual item as well?

Comment: @Jake: see edit, is this the function you are looking for?

Comment: That works perfectly. Learned something new with this line `l@(Lambda _ _) = [l] ` Many thanks